# How can I compute the total hours from timein and timeout from my SQL database?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I want to compute the total time (timeout - timein) in hours in multiple rows with rows that has employee_ID value 1 and getting those values in between two datetimepicker? Is this possible?

Comment: You talk about rows, are they database or datagridview rows? In case your problem is with a database, you provide no SQL attempted or table structure so there is not enough info. To me it is quite unclear, I would suggest you to edit your question and improve it.

Comment: they are from a datagridview and the datagridview is from a database

Answer (score 0):

Just filter on Employee_ID = 1 and the in and out times between the picked dates.

Then you can find the *total hours* for each row:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = timeOut.Subtract(timeIn);
double totalHours = timeSpan.TotalHours;
```

and sum these - like:

```
double totalHours = 0;
// loop the filtered rows:
    totalHours += timeOut.Subtract(timeIn).TotalHours;
//
// assign totalHours to a textbox to display the result.
```

Comment: i will reexplain my question(sorry my english is bad). in my c# form there is a textbox where you input the Employee_ID and a button that when clicked it will show rows (Employee_ID,Time_In,Time_Out) with values from my database to the datagridview.

Comment: Then let your click event continue looping the resulting rows and summing up the total hours using an expression similar to the one above.

Comment: i want to get the total hours in the displayed datagridview in ![my form](https://ibb.co/fStCiL) @Gustav

Comment: Yes - loop through the rows of your datagridview, calculate the total hours for each row, and add these to the variable `totalHours` as shown. When done, assign the value of the variable to the label or textbox that will display the total: `= totalHours.ToString();`.